# Excluding files on a branch merge with subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-merge

I have created a feature branch off of the trunk for my project and the feature branch requires some project file configuration changes for it to work. When I merge the feature back to the trunk I don't want the project file merged. Is there any way to selectively merge certain files to the trunk? Perhaps an exclusion of the project file itself.

Answer (score 7):

A merge in svn is a two-step process; first you merge the changes from your branch into a working copy, then you commit the merged files into the repository. This gives you a chance to resolve conflicts or make other changes before committing the merge.

After you do the merge into your working copy, you can selectively revert the changes to individual files before you commit the merge to the repository.

Comment: Ok, I figured that might be an option I could try. Visual Studio tries to reload the project as soon as the merge is finished and the project won't reload because of a changed IISUrl setting in the project file. I might have to do the merge from Tortoise instead of VS and then jump back into VS.